# iOS Constraints Way off On Device Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I have an iPad app with a nice layout that looks fine in every version of the iPad simulator (iPad 2, iPad Air, iPad Retina). However when I sync it to my actual iPad Air 2, the constraints of some assets are *way* off.

I've tried uninstalling the app, restarting the iPad, clean builds, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Any debugging suggestions?

**Update**

I'm updating with screenshots that show the difference between simulator and device (albeit with arbitrary assets).

Target Device (iPad Air 2)
[image: Target Device]

Simulator (iPad Air)
[image: Simulator]

Comment: That's a weird one. Maybe some screen shots might help give a clue?

Comment: Not sure I can do that just now, but if it comes to that I'll create some screenshots. Its's just things like buttons that are anchored off the bottom are way at the top, an image that is usually centered is not, etc.

Comment: Version of iOS are the same?